# WPF - Prism : Show regions in dialog window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have Dialog Window with a `TabControl` which contains 4 tabs, each tab contains a region.

**DialogWindowTestView.xaml**

```
<TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" TabStripPlacement="Left">
    <TabItem Header="General">
        <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="GeneralRegion" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Materials">
        <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MaterialsRegion" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Design">
        <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="DesignRegion" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Units">
        <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="UnitsRegion" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I've tried two methods in order to display the regions inside the tabs.
First I used `RegisterViewWithRegion`. this shows the regions correctly, **but the view gets called once when first open the dialog window, and after closing the window and re-opening it, the view constructor gets called many times each time the user opens the dialog window.**

*Edit: It's the view inside the tabItem that gets called many times, not the dialog window.*

**DialogWindowTestViewModel.cs**

```
if (!regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("GeneralRegion")) {
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("GeneralRegion", typeof(GeneralView));
}
if (!regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("MaterialsRegion")) {
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MaterialsRegion", typeof(MaterialsView));
}
if (!regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("DesignRegion")) {
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("DesignRegion", typeof(DesignView));
}
if (!regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("UnitsRegion")) {
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("UnitsRegion", typeof(UnitSetView));
}
```

The second method is `regionManager.RequestNavigate`, this shows the regions correctly, **but after closing and re-opining the view all regions disappear.** the window will be with all the tabs empty.

**DialogWindowTestView.xaml.cs**

```
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this, regionManager);
RegionManager.UpdateRegions();
```

**DialogWindowTestViewModel.cs**

```
container.RegisterType<object, GeneralView>(typeof(GeneralView).FullName);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("GeneralRegion", typeof(GeneralView).FullName);

container.RegisterType<object, MaterialsView>(typeof(MaterialsView).FullName);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MaterialsRegion", typeof(MaterialsView).FullName);

container.RegisterType<object, DesignView>(typeof(DesignView).FullName);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("DesignRegion", typeof(DesignView).FullName);

container.RegisterType<object, UnitSetView>(typeof(UnitSetView).FullName);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("UnitsRegion", typeof(UnitSetView).FullName);
```

What is the best way in order to show the regions correctly without any unwanted behaviors?

Comment: What's wrong with the first approach? Are you expecting the views not to be re-created when the dialog is closed and re-opened?

Comment: @mm8 The view constructor gets called multiple times each time the user opens the view, and the number of times the constructor gets called increased everytime the window closed and re-opened. the first time the view constructor gets called once when creating the view, second time it gets called like 3 times. third time gets called even more.
**It's the view inside the tabItem that gets called many times, not the dialog window.**

Comment: In the views or view models used in the dialog, are you subscribing to events, or registering application commands that you do not unsubscribe or unregister when the dialog closes? That can cause similar behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach: RegisterViewWithRegion is a global registration that will live for the lifetime of the application.  To make the registration, you need not check for region existence.  You should not register multiple times, that will result in behavior you observing.

Move registration out of the view constructor so that they are made only once.

Remove the check for region existence.

Your check for region existence fails and registrations are performed multiple times because when the view is closed it is removed from visual tree and a special region behavior removes the regions from region manager.